# tvOS video: How to set duration of video on metadata

Tags: ios, avplayer, tvos

I'm setting the title and description as metadata for an AVPlayer video in tvOS. 
How can set the player duration in metadata?

Answer (score 0):

the info overlay should automatically display the correct duration. if not, you can try this:

```
let duration = player?.currentItem?.duration
let titleItem = AVMutableMetadataItem()

titleItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle
titleItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon
titleItem.locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
titleItem.value = "My Video"
titleItem.duration = duration
```

Comment: Suppose my video duration is 32 mins and 55 seconds. By default player is displaying round off value of the duration i.e. 33 min. Now i would like to display only 32 min.  How could I do?  I tried using the steps which you mentioned but it didn't work. Please let me know, if there is any other solution

Comment: try this: `let minutes = (lround(duration) / 60) % 60`

Comment: Following is the code I am using to display title                            
AVMutableMetadataItem *titleMetadataItem = [[AVMutableMetadataItem alloc] init];
    titleMetadataItem.locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    titleMetadataItem.key = AVMetadataCommonKeyTitle;
    titleMetadataItem.keySpace = AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon;
    titleMetadataItem.value = @"title";
    titleMetadataItem.duration = self.player.currentItem.duration                         Now how do i get the min value from duration and then again set the value. I tried setting the hard coded value but it doesn't worked.

Comment: when are you creating the metadata? the duration might not be there yet. Take a look at the documentation. you need to check the items status. Only if it is `ReadyToPlay` you have the duration of the video. Then you can do `let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(item.duration)`

Comment: I am creating the player metadata on player item status is ready to play. Even then it is picking the round off value of the duration.

Comment: and what happens if you try to convert the minutes back to a `CMTime`? `let duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(player!.currentItem!.duration) let minutesRounded = lround(duration) / 60 let minutesDuration = CMTime(seconds: Double(minutesRounded) * 60, preferredTimescale: 1)`